# Is there a way to bind a Model's .change() trigger to a View's .render() function without creating more than one?

Tags: backbone.js

A View normally expects an object with these attributes before it can render:

```
{ el: '#someelement', model: someModel }
```

A View also allows us to bind the model's events to functions in the view:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind('change', this.renderFromModel, this);
},

render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
},

renderFromModel: function() {
    var t = _.template($('#some-template').html());
    $('item-' + this.cid).html(t(this.toJSON()));
    return this;
},
```

The problem is that the first time we instantiate a View for rendering, it is expecting an object with a Model in it; and the second time we render the view when it is called from within the Model, it is not.  Because of this, I end up creating two render() functions.

Is there a better way of achieving single item render that can also respond to model.change() events?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

i think you need to ensure your render method is always bound the view by calling underscore.js' bindAll method.

```
SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, "render");
    this.model.bind('change', this.render);
  },

  render: function(){
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});
```

Comment: oh geeze, thanks!  I guess I really need to read up on underscore.js

Comment: you can use this.$el instead of $(this.el): http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el (documentation)

Answer (score 13):

A better solution is to use the [listenTo function](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo):

```
SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
  },

  render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});
```

This way the view object is aware of the bindings it made, and all of them can be removed with the [stopListening function](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-stopListening) and doesn't need to call bind or bindAll explicitly. Last but not least the code is cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.$el.html` as mentioned in another comment ?

Comment: Maybe this is for a more recent version of BackboneJS, but don't you also have to set the context for the function in the `render` property? That is, you have to add `_.bindAll(this, 'render')` in the `initialize` property of the view.

Answer (score 12):

Use _.bind() method to set scope

```
 this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this));
```

Comment: thanks ant_Ti.  I read the documentation over and over, but it still escapes my understanding.  How come that works?

Comment: I think the behavior of
this.model.bind("change" , this.render , this); 
and
this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this));
are different, though the first one also defines the scope on this, but in my case what ant_Ti had suggested worked

Answer (score 6):

As of Backbone 0.9.2 (and possibly earlier), the `on()` or `bind()` function (as well as its counterpart `off()` or `unbind()`) takes an optional `context` parameter to use for `this` when called.

So,

```
SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, "render");
    this.model.bind('change', this.render);
  },

  render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});
```

can become

```
SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
  },

  render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});
```

See [the documentation for `on()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on).

Comment: @muistooshort Yep! Good catch. I copied and pasted from the answer above (which is obviously a little old).

Answer (score 0):

create model instance in the view

```
var myapp.myView  = new View({
        model: new Model
    });
```

and when you initialize the Backbone.View inside add this .. which  render will be called  any time there is change is model attributes from it's defaults

```
this.model.bind('change', this.render,this)
```